# Why does using square brackets cause a subscripted value is neither array nor pointer nor vector error?

Tags: c

I'm new to C and I'm trying to become familiar with the basics, I thought id make a program that just takes an array and uses a function to print the information in the array. However, when I try to compile this program I get the following error:

```
error: subscripted value is neither array nor pointer nor vector
           printf(" %d", data[i]);
                             ^
```

The code I'm currently using is below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int maxReturn(int a, int b, int c, int d);

int main(){

    int arr[4] = {1,4,8,2};

    int max = maxReturn(arr[0],arr[1],arr[2],arr[3]);

    printf("%d\n", max);

    return 0;
}

int maxReturn(int a, int b, int c, int d){

    int data = {a,b,c,d};
    
    for(int i; i < 4; i++){
        printf(" %d", data[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    
    return data;

}
```

I'm at a bit of a loss as to what is wrong here because in the tutorials I'm following they print out values by using data[i]. Why is this not ok?

Comment: Look at one of them tutorials once again. Does it say `int data = { .... } ? Better yet, get a reputable *book*.

Comment: That bad huh, care to recommend a book?

Comment: That is not the sole concerning [error in this code](https://godbolt.org/z/qn1avq1zc), especially whence you heighten warning levels and treat all warnings as errors (which you should *always* do).  Language syntax is critical. You're fortunate, to be honest. Your mistakes cause a failure to compile (and thus run). Its the ones that *pass* compilation, but end up doing something entirely different than your intent due to erroneous misunderstanding that can be the real bears to root out.

Comment: if you don't get a compile error for `int data = {a,b,c,d};` then adjust your settings. The compiler can help you identify bad code

Comment: One good book is Modern C by Jens Gustedt. The other one is the classic K&R. It is outdated at places, but very well written, so still worth a read.

Answer (score 2):

You are declaring an `int` using the `{...}` construct as if you were initializing an array. Probably, you forgot to declare `data` as an array of `int`.

Replacing the line:

```
int data = {a,b,c,d};
```

with:

```
int data[4] = {a,b,c,d};
```

should fix your problem.

**EDIT:**

You might not even define the size of the array in this case, because using the `{...}` construct the compiler computes the size of the array at build-time.

Comment: Why not let the compile calculate the size (`int data[] = { a, b, c, d, };`)?

Comment: Yes, you are right, I just followed the declaration he made in the `main`. 
Now I update the answer.